# How to share my ec2 instance to other account within my organization?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to share my ec2,s3,elastic beanstalk instance to other account within my organization?

Comment: What do you mean by "share"? What capabilities are you wanting to grant them? For example, should they be allowed to delete resources? View resources? Change the configuration of your Elastic Beanstalk app? Please edit your question to add more details, with an example if possible.

Comment: When I login to my AWS account, I will be able to view/edit all the ec2,s3 and other resources that I created. I want them(other users in same organization) to view/edit all these resources.

Comment: If the other people have credentials to login to the same AWS Account, and sufficient permissions to view/edit those resources, they will be able to do so. Are they able to login? Are they currently able to view/edit the resources? If not, what error is appearing and what permissions have they been granted?

Comment: ohh my bad.., I figured out the problem, we created resources in different regions. thanks for replying me..

Comment: Good you found a solution! Feel free to delete this question if you don't think it will benefit other readers.